# How would you describe 'swinging into a car'?

Tags: phrase-requests

I mean a word/phrase for grabbing the roof of your car, and swinging your body in through the open window.

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that the "Dukes of Hazzard" actor who made this famous spent a *very* long time learning how to do it safely and reliably. Here's a link to someone trying but effectively failing... [*Man uses ‘Dukes of Hazzard’ slide through window to thwart car thief.*](https://globalnews.ca/news/2452586/watch-man-uses-dukes-of-hazzard-slide-through-window-to-thwart-car-thief/) Presumably the journalist who wrote that headline couldn't think of any "better" description than ***‘Dukes of Hazzard’ slide***.

Comment: I would say *swinging into a car*. What's wrong with the original phrase?